# find a measure fuction for each $C_{m}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,T,\mu)$ a space of measure and let $E_{1},..,E_{n}\in T$. For each $m\in{1,...,n}$ we define $$C_{m}=\{x\in X: x\in E_j \mbox{ for exactly m index} j\in \{1,...,n\}\}$$

Find a measure function $f:X\to \{1,...,n\}$ such tha for all $m\in{1,..,n} $ we have that $C_{m}=x\in X:f(x)=m$. Furthermore C_m is in T.  Any hint pls¡ thanks

my idea was take a measur function I really try. but anyway doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n{\bf 1}_{E_i}(x)$$
where ${\bf 1}_{E_i}$ is the indicator funcrion of the set $E_i$.